# Is there a way to speed up restoring data from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, restore

- OS: Windows10 x64
- HDD: 1TB
- RAM: 8GB
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4460
- PostgreSQL: 9.6

I want to import almost *37GB* data from MySQL into PostgreSQL, and the data is sql file, which full of `INSERT INTO tbl_1 VALUES(x, x, x);` statements.

I'm using `\i data.sql` to import it, but after 15 hours work, the PostgreSQL's data size is only *1GB*. While during this 15 hours, there are no other tasks running, only the importing.

So, is there anyway i can do to speed up the procedure?

Comment: `mysqldump` is willing to emit batch inserts; do they work in PostgreSQL?  For MySQL it is a 10x speedup.  Also, what happens with the indexes?

Comment: @RickJames yeah, the batch inserts have `"` around table name, I use **sed** tool to remove them. For indexes, i remove all indexes creation in schemas file, only left table creation.

Comment: The default would be backtics; did you change to use quotes instead?

Comment: think the fasted way will be always copy from csv - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html, so if prepare csv file from SQL than copy into table, it must be faster

Comment: @RickJames My colleague give me the exported MySQL file(contains one schemas file, and one batch inserts file which use quotes). These two make a difference while importing into PG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not running the `\i data.sql` command within a transaction, then the insertion of every row is getting committed individually.  This is very slow.

If you can't switch over to a `copy` based method, then at least run your load script in a transaction.  For example, issue `BEGIN;` before the `\i`.  Don't forget to commit afterwards.  Or run the whole script with `psql -1 -f data.sql`

Comment: sorry for silly questions, if i use `COPY`, do i still need `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

Comment: No, all the tuples inserted by the same COPY will automatically be part of a single transaction.  But it also won't hurt, and may be a good idea for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You should try pgloader : http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html It can load data from MySQL to PostgreSQL using `COPY` mode, which is faster than `INSERT`.

Comment: I used `COPY`, it's really fast, thanks a lot.